# store entry to database according to my selection from drop down menu

Tags: php, mysql

I’m glad to ask you again, I have registration page for employee vacation consist of 5 fields 
"employee name", "vacation type"(one day vacation, part day vacation, long day vacation), "date of Vacation"(used for one day vacation and part of day vacation), "from" (if insert hour then part of day vacation & if insert date then long term vacation)and final field is "to" (if insert hour then part of day vacation & if insert date then long term vacation)

so i need to make a query to insert these data to my database according to the selection of vacation type if chose one day vacation then no need the insertion of ("from" and "to" fields) to database just insert employee name, one day vacation, and date of vacation.

and if i chose part day vacation then i must enter employee name, vacation type= part day,vacation date, and last 2 fields must be entered as hours which i already select it for ex: from=08:30 AM and to=10:30 AM.

and if i chose long day vacation then i must enter employee name, vacation type= long day,vacation date, and last 2 fields must be entered as date which i already select it for ex: from=10/9/2014 and to=11/9/2014.

this is a part of my work but i cant make it work in one query

```
$employee_name=$_POST['employee_name']; 
$today = date("d/m/Y");           //date of vacation
$vacation=$_POST['vacation'];     //part day, one day and long term vacation
$start_hour=$_POST['start_hour']; //if i select part of day vacation hour from drop list
$end_hour=$_POST['end_hour'];     //if i select part of day vacation hour from drop list
$day_start=$_POST['day_start'];   //if i select long term vacation from drop list
$day_end=$_POST['day_end'];       //if i select long term vacation from drop list
```

i refer to exactly what i should do in the query below

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $vac_table(name, type, date, from, to)VALUES('$employee_name', '$vacation','$today','$start_hour'if part time and  '$day_start' if long time, '$end_hour' if part time  and '$day_end' if long time )";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

i know it was very long question but I hope that you excuse me since am joiner in this field and asked you to help me many thanks

Comment: MySQL needs more joiners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, it seems that you only have one date field in the database. You need `start_date` and `end_date`.

Based on your conditions, the following code makes sure the data is valid, and inserts it.

You only need only one table

```
if ($vacation == 'one day') {
    $start_hour = '';
    $end_hour = '';
    $day_start = $_POST['day_start'];   //if i select long term vacation from drop list
    $day_end = $_POST['day_start'];
}

// for part day, end date is the same as start date
if ($vacation == 'part day') {
    $day_end = $_POST['day_start'];  
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO `vacations` (`name`, `type`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `start_hour`, `end_hour`) VALUES ('$employee_name', '$vacation', '$day_start', '$day_end', '$start_hour', '$end_hour')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

You can also make `start_date` and `end_date` as datetime fields, and do something like:

```
if ($vacation == 'one day') {
    $day_start = $_POST['day_start'];   //if i select long term vacation from drop list
    $day_end = $_POST['day_start'];
}

// for part day, end date is the same as start date
if ($vacation == 'part day') {
    $day_end = $_POST['day_start'];  
}

 $day_start .= ' ' . $_POST['start_hour'];
 $day_end .= ' ' . $_POST['end_hour'];
```

then

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `vacations` (`name`, `type`, `start_date`, `end_date`) VALUES ('$employee_name', '$vacation', '$day_start', '$day_end')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: OK i seems good but if i select part day then time as hour start must be inserted to from field and hour end must be inserted to "to" field.

Comment: Do you have only one hour field?

Comment: in html page i used 2 fields as text to insert information required about hour for ex if i chose part day then i must fill field of start hour 08:00 and another field of end as 10:00 these value taken from this page called $start_hour=$_POST['start_hour'];
$end_hour=$_POST['end_hour'];

Comment: this should work, because $start_hour is inserted in the `start_hour` field and $end_hour in the `end_hour` field, as they are taken form the form.

Comment: but in my data base i only have employee name, vacation type, date of vacation, from, to so how can i apply your query in my data base since i have only these fields above and you write (`name`, `type`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `start_hour`, `end_hour`)

Comment: If you want to save start hour and end hour, you either need 2 hour fields, or put the time in the date and use no hour field

Comment: so i cant save hour in from field if i chose part day and save date in same field if i chose long term, you mean that right ???

Comment: for consistency, you should either have 2 fields for hour, or none